# .../sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-server failed

Tags: java, android, gradle

I recently started working on an android project which accesses microphone resources to save sound files, however I've been unable to test it as of yet due to a huge slurry of build errors I've been getting. I'm not sure how to get a more specific error, as I haven't been presented with a stack trace, so I'm going to paste examples of the error messages the gradle build window has given me:

```
.../app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/res/values-v17/values-v17.xml
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
.../app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
```

Any ideas what error is causing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like some kind of path error. Either the build cannot find the libraries, or they are not installed. Check the SDK path is correct, then use SDK manager to ensure you have the right android packages for the target build level and do a project clean